# how can I enforce english language in a git commit message?

Tags: git, policy, commit-message

Is it possible to enforce english in a commit message?

At the moment, git commit messages in our projects are a mix of 2 languages and the team keeps forgetting git messages good practices. Could we at least show a warning?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe a custom commit hook?

Comment: Of course, a hook. But with what code? I'm not asking for the complete answer, just some directions. For example, is there any web service to infer a text language?

Answer (score 0):

If you can find a program that looks at a block of text and tells you whether it believes that block of text to be in a language other than English, I suppose you could set up hooks.

Finding/recommending a tool that processes text in that way would be off-topic for SO; so I'll say only that I think it will be challenging.  But supposing you have one, you would have two options.  You could do one or both of the following:

First, you could create a pre-commit hook.  This is a hook that runs locally, and therefore must be set up by each developer.  (Which means it only gets run if the developer willingly cooperates.)  The advantage is that any problem gets caught right away.

Second, you could create a pre-receive hook on your shared repo(s) (e.g. typically `origin`), assuming it's hosted in a way that allows you to set up hooks.  This has the advantage that it can't be circumvented either by accident when setting up a new local repo, or by an uncooperative developer.  But, if a developer makes several commits with unacceptable messages locally and then tries to push, they'll have to do something like an interactive rebase to edit all of the messages before they can push.

You can use the two in combination, of course, so that the pre-receive hook enforces the rule's integrity in the shared repo, and the desire to avoid the need to rework gives developers an incentive to set up the local pre-commit hook as well.

If you want to pursue this, I'd recommend you look over the git hook documentation: https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks

Comment: yeah, I know about hooks, but the problem is the other part ("a program that looks at a block of text and tells you whether it believes that block of text to be in a language other than English"). Maybe the question should be different, then. But I'm surprised that something like this doesn't exist already as a git-hook.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use a pre-commit hook, to run a script, what validate your commit.

So if you can find a program, what can determine if it's valid English, then you can validate your commits.

Or you can use pull requests, and just reject any non English commit.